# Flutter: List of Widgets with Multiple Entries Functionality

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

im trying to get my head around implementing something like the below

[image: layout mockup]

Im thinking of creating a List of Widgets with each widget in the List having the + symbol and having the ability to add/remove multiple items under that category

how would one store this if you need to tally up the total for all categories in the list of widgets,

I was thinking of creating a Master List and storing key value pairs but then this will be hard to keep track when you need to remove items,

Im also taking into consideration is draft entry, so a user will be able to save what they have currently entered and i will need to re-populate all the current data back into the relevant entred categories

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data class as

```
class Data{
    String name;
    List<double> quantities;
    Data({this.name,this.quantities});
    //This will return the total for one row 
    getTotal(){
        double total=0;
        quantities.map((quantity)=>total+=quantity);
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Then you can take a `List<Data>` and put your values and use `ListView.Builder`

```
List<Data> allData=List();
//You have to store your initial data in the list 1st
return ListView.Builder(
    itemCount:allData.length,
    builder:(context,position){
     Data data=allData[position];
     return ListTile(
         //You can put your row here with the data 
     ); 
    }
);
```

Then in the `onPressed` of add button you have to take input and add the amount into the `quantities` list of the data object and you can simply call `setState((){})`